# Is there any way by which i can do vlookup in pandas python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to do vlookup using pandas in python,but getting wrong result.
I have two excel workbooks:
First:

```
Share Folder name   Unnamed: 3  value2  Unnamed: 5
A                   INDIA       11      Change
B                   INDIA       15      Change
C                   INDIA       33      Change
A                   INDIA       12      Change
B                   INDIA       74      Change
A                   INDIA       740     Change
```

Second:

```
Share Folder name       email: 5
A                       abc@gmail.com
B                       bca@gmail.com
C                       gba@gmail.com
```

I want to do vlookup by using First and second table and want to get following result:

```
Share Folder name   Unnamed: 3  value2  Unnamed:5   email:5
A                   INDIA       11      Change     abc@gmail.com
B                   INDIA       15      Change     bca@gmail.com
C                   INDIA       33      Change     gba@gmail.com
A                   INDIA       12      Change     abc@gmail.com
B                   INDIA       74      Change     bca@gmail.com
A                   INDIA       740     Change     abc@gmail.com
```

I tried following code but didnt workded:

```
First.merge(Second,on='Share Folder name')
First.merge(Second, on="Share Folder name", how = 'left')
```

What i want is repeating values in First should get email id's corresponding
to the Second table where values are not repeating.

Comment: Please check dupe, e.g. by `map`. If still not working please be more specific

Comment: your code should work in Theory, make sure that the ID's are exactly alike (no whitespace or anything)

Comment: Here my comparison column is share folder name and i want where ever it sees A,B,C whether there are multiple values it will automatically give email id's corresponding to each A,B,C regardless how many times it comes.